# How to replace a multipart message schema in a map without replacing the map

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-mapper

I have an orchestration map that maps two source messages into one destination message.  When the schema for one of the source messages changes, I was hoping to be able to click on the input message part and select "Replace Schema" to refresh the schema for just the message part affected.  Instead I can only replace the entire multipart message schema with the single message part schema.

[image]

My only other option seems to be to generate a new map from the orchestration transform shape, but this means I have to recreate all the links in my map...

Does anyone know of a more efficient way to update this type of schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided for now to do this by modifying the xml of the map file.  If anyone out there has any better ideas, I'd still like to hear them.  Thanks!

Comment: I have found editing the .btm file by hand, as you mentioned, to be the only way to handle this without losing your map links.

Comment: I often edit the BTM file by hand, as it often saves a lot of time and quite easy to do, although has to be done carefully.

Answer (score 0):

After creating maps in the orchestration project, i moved them to maps project by copy and paste and change the namespace. Now everything looks good. But I found interesting problem.

When i try to reference these maps  in the orchestraion I am able to see two schema namepaces under the maps references dll. one has newly moved maps and another one has old ones.

Can any one explain why? Is that sth i am doing wrong. or Biztalk 06 (vs2005) is behaving funny....

Then i created a new map in the Maps project and copied the xslt from orchestrioan map and pasted there. If i go with this approach i am unable to see two namespaces in the orchestraiton shape while referencing.